# Proof of $C^{T}DC$ is always symmetric for real matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I am trying to prove that $C^{T}DC$ is symmetric. I start by assuming that $B=C^{T}DC$. Using the rule of multiplication of matrices,

$$ b_{ij} = \sum \limits_{l} \sum \limits_{k} c_{il}^{T} d_{lk} c_{kj} = \sum \limits_{l} \sum\limits_{k} c_{li} d_{lk} c_{kj}$$

Similarly,

$$b_{ji} = \sum \limits_{l} \sum \limits_{k} c_{jl}^{T} d_{lk} c_{ki} = \sum \limits_{l} \sum \limits_{k} c_{lj} d_{lk} c_{ki} = \sum \limits_{l} \sum \limits_{k} c_{ki} d_{lk} c_{lj}$$

Since $k$ and $l$ are dummy indices, we can interchange them. (Right?)

This gives us

$$b_{ji} = \sum \limits_{l} \sum \limits_{k} c_{li} d_{kl} c_{kj} = b_{ij}$$

This proves that $C^{T}DC$  is always symmetric provided that $D$ is symmetric. Is this proof correct?

Comment: Is $D$ diagonal? Also, I think that should be $d_{lk}$ in the middle of those sums.

Comment: @Arthur, you are right. I have edited the question. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know the identity $(AB)^\top = B^\top A^\top$ ?

Comment: @Surb, yes, but I didn't come to my mind. Thank you.

Comment: Also, note that $D$ needs to be symmetric for your statement to be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your proof is correct.

However, here is a much simpler proof:
$$
B^T = (C^TDC)^T = C^TD^T(C^T)^T = C^TDC = B
$$